# Why i can't use the Conditional Rendering like this?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, vite

Can someone help me?

I'm making a component in react, but I came across the "',' expected" error in the code below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../styles/Listagem.css'

const Turmas = ({tipoEscolha}) => {
    
    return (
        {tipoEscolha && (
            <>
                <label htmlFor="TURMA1">Turma 1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA1" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA1"/>

                <label htmlFor="TURMA2">Turma 2</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA2" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA2"/>

                <label htmlFor="TURMA3">Turma 3</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA3" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA3"/>

                <label htmlFor="TURMA4">Turma 4</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA4" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA4"/>

                <label htmlFor="TURMA5">Turma 5</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA5" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA5"/>

                <label htmlFor="TURMA6">Turma 6</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA6" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA6"/>

                <label htmlFor="TURMA7">Turma 7</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA7" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA7"/>
            </>
        )}
    );
}
 
export default Turmas;
```

The error occurs in the 7th line " - tipoEscolha &&"
/
Can anyone tell what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your return statement in a React Fragment `<>`. React components must return JSX Elements, or null.

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/Listagem.css';

const Turmas = ({ tipoEscolha }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {tipoEscolha && (
        <>
          <label htmlFor="TURMA1">Turma 1</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA1" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA1" />

          <label htmlFor="TURMA2">Turma 2</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA2" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA2" />

          <label htmlFor="TURMA3">Turma 3</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA3" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA3" />

          <label htmlFor="TURMA4">Turma 4</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA4" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA4" />

          <label htmlFor="TURMA5">Turma 5</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA5" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA5" />

          <label htmlFor="TURMA6">Turma 6</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA6" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA6" />

          <label htmlFor="TURMA7">Turma 7</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA7" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA7" />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Turmas;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the syntax of brackets in only valid inside JSX so you can write down javascript code during compilation

Plain javascript dont know that `{}` syntax thats why you get an error, you could do this instead:

```
const Turmas = ({tipoEscolha}) => {
    
   if(tipoEscolha)
     return (
       <>
         <label htmlFor="TURMA1">Turma 1</label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="TURMA1" name="TURMAS" value="TURMA1"/>
       </>
     );

   return <></> // if tipoEscolha is false
}
```

PS: This is called [conditional rendering](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)